# Telegram bot in Java does not start

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, telegram-bot

Error: **java: cannot access java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture class file for java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture not found**

Connected the library using Maven. Here is the TelegramBotsApi code to start the bot:

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        try {
            TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);
            botsApi.registerBot(new telegaBot());
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code of the bot itself:

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;

public class telegaBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "bot_name";
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return "token";
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    }
}
```

Here are Java, Maven and IDEA versions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbZKE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QlF1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMguu.png)

Comment: class names should start with capital letter, so `TelegramBot` instead of `telegamBot`

Comment: Please paste the error about Completable future from your picture and remove all the images (https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3fSY.png). They are not allowed in this question.

Comment: What's your JDK version?

Comment: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. What does "Connected the library using Maven" mean? Exactly how are you trying to run your program?